# create SQL table from existing table using pyodbc/turbodc in python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I would like to create a SQL table from an existing table. I'm using the turbodbc module (which is very similar to pyodbc).

```
# connect to database
conn = turbodbc.connect(connection_string="my_connection_string")
cursor = conn.cursor()
# execute SQL code
cursor.execute((" create table Test_Puts as"
                " select * from OptionValue"
                " where call_put = 'P'"))
```

However, I get the error message:

```
ODBC error
state: 42000
native error code: 156
message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
```

Comment: Try to put your select code in brackets () start before select and end after 'P'

Comment: @VBoka I get "Incorrect syntax near '('" , native error code 102

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this syntax:

```
select * into Test_Puts from  OptionValue where call_put = 'P'
```

So, instead of this:

```
" create table Test_Puts as"
" select * from OptionValue"
" where call_put = 'P'"
```

use this:

```
" select * into Test_Puts"
" from  OptionValue"
" where call_put = 'P'"
```

Comment: Hi @thomas.mac , so, does this helps ? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the upside is it does not get an error, but the downside is it takes a very long time to run, so not sure what end result looks like. Is there more an efficient way to run the code?

Comment: Hi @thomas.mac what is the number of rows you are selecting ?

Comment: 670 million rows !